# How to mount local volumes in docker machine

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I am trying to use docker-machine with docker-compose. The file docker-compose.yml has definitions as follows:

```
web:
  build: .
  command: ./run_web.sh
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    - db:db
    - rabbitmq:rabbit
    - redis:redis
```

When running `docker-compose up -d` all goes well until trying to execute the command and an error is produced:

> Cannot start container b58e2dfa503b696417c1c3f49e2714086d4e9999bd71915a53502cb6ef43936d: [8] System error: exec: "./run_web.sh": stat ./run_web.sh: no such file or directory

Local volumes are not mounted to the remote machine. Whats the recommended strategy to mount the local volumes with the webapps' code?

Comment: The structure of the project and docker-compose.yml is similar to this tutorial http://www.syncano.com/configuring-running-django-celery-docker-containers-pt-1/

Comment: This should be in the docker-compose documents as a helpful hint to those that might be getting started using compose locally. Would have saved me hours of WTF moments trying to figure out why the heck my file path was wrong or not found. No I just feel silly.

Answer (score 95):

Docker-machine automounts the users directory... But sometimes that just isn't enough.

I don't know about docker 1.6, but in 1.8 you *CAN* add an additional mount to docker-machine

## Add Virtual Machine Mount Point (part 1)

**CLI**: (Only works when machine is stopped)

`VBoxManage sharedfolder add <machine name/id> --name <mount_name> --hostpath <host_dir> --automount`

So an example in windows would be

```
/c/Program\ Files/Oracle/VirtualBox/VBoxManage.exe sharedfolder add default --name e --hostpath 'e:\' --automount
```

**GUI**: (does NOT require the machine be stopped)

1. Start "Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager"
2. Right-Click `<machine name>` (default)
3. Settings...
4. Shared Folders
5. The Folder+ Icon on the Right (Add Share)
6. Folder Path: `<host dir>` (e:)
7. Folder Name: `<mount name>` (e)
8. Check on "Auto-mount" and "Make Permanent" (Read only if you want...) (The auto-mount is sort of pointless currently...)

## Mounting in boot2docker (part 2)

**Manually mount in boot2docker**:

1. There are various ways to log in, use "Show" in "Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager", or ssh/putty into docker by IP address `docker-machine ip default`, etc...
2. `sudo mkdir -p <local_dir>`
3. `` sudo mount -t vboxsf -o defaults,uid=`id -u docker`,gid=`id -g docker` <mount_name> <local_dir> ``

But this is only good until you restart the machine, and then the mount is lost...

**Adding an automount to boot2docker**:

While logged into the machine

1. Edit/create (as root) `/mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh`, sda1 may be different for you...
2. Add

   ```
   mkdir -p <local_dir>
   mount -t vboxsf -o defaults,uid=`id -u docker`,gid=`id -g docker` <mount_name> <local_dir>
   ```

With these changes, you should have a new mount point. This is one of the few files I could find that is called on boot and is persistent. Until there is a better solution, this should work.

---

Old method: **Less recommended**, but left as an alternative

- Edit (as root) `/mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/profile`, sda1 may be different for you...
- Add

  ```
  add_mount() {
    if ! grep -q "try_mount_share $1 $2" /etc/rc.d/automount-shares ; then
      echo "try_mount_share $1 $2" >> /etc/rc.d/automount-shares
    fi
  }

  add_mount <local dir> <mount name>
  ```

As a **last resort**, you can take the slightly more tedious alternative, and you can just modify the boot image.

- `git -c core.autocrlf=false clone https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker.git`
- `cd boot2docker`
- `git -c core.autocrlf=false checkout v1.8.1` #or your appropriate version
- Edit `rootfs/etc/rc.d/automount-shares`
- Add `try_mount_share <local_dir> <mount_name>` line right before fi at the end. For example

  ```
  try_mount_share /e e
  ```

  Just be sure not to set the  to anything the os needs, like /bin, etc...
- `docker build -t boot2docker .` #This will take about an hour the first time :(
- `docker run --rm boot2docker > boot2docker.iso`
- Backup the old boot2docker.iso and copy your new one in its place, in ~/.docker/machine/machines/

This does work, it's just long and complicated

docker version 1.8.1, docker-machine version 0.4.0

Comment: For anyone having problems with this, I'm pretty sure I had to make the local paths match the ones in the docker-machine. Also docker-compose seemed to succeed in mounting the volumes while regular docker didn't -- not sure why.

Comment: Created a script for the solution mentioned here. Works on latest docker 1.10 and docker-machine 0.6.0 gist.github.com/cristobal/fcb0987871d7e1f7449e

Comment: Different resources talk about using `/mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/profile`, can you explain why you switched to using `/mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh`? Also, striking through this much text doesn't contribute to the readability of your answer ;-)

Comment: @Forage Point taken about my formatting :). I do not remember off hand why I suggest the `bootlocal.sh` method anymore. All I can say is it looks cleaner to just use a mount command like I did in `bootlocal.sh` than it does in the profile. Also, typically, I believe the `profile` could be run multiple times, and a mount only needs to be run once, so it makes more sense. But both can work.

Comment: LOVE IT! Thank you!

Comment: The `Add Virtual Machine Mount Point (part 1)` is all you need to do in latest Docker Toolbox v18.09.3. And even this is not required if mount path on host machine is under `C:\Users` directory. See my answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56454381/758991).

Comment: @Andy is it possible to manage ownership of specific shared subfolders? I have a problem with preparing setup of Postgres Docker container with persistent data. Changing ownership on nor host neither guest work. I could mount only Postgres data directory as shared with guest, but I would rather prefer to share entire project directory and mount its subdirectories freely with simple `-v` docker switch during my work.

Answer (score 28):

Also ran into this issue and it looks like local volumes are not mounted when using docker-machine. A hack solution is to

1. get the current working directory of the docker-machine instance `docker-machine ssh <name> pwd`
2. use a command line tool like `rsync` to copy folder to remote system

   ```
   rsync -avzhe ssh --progress <name_of_folder> username@remote_ip:<result _of_pwd_from_1>.
   ```

The default pwd is /root so the command above would be `rsync -avzhe ssh --progress <name_of_folder> username@remote_ip:/root`

NB: you would need to supply the password for the remote system. You can quickly create one by ssh into the remote system and creating a password.

3. change the volume mount point in your `docker-compose.yml` file from `.:/app` to `/root/<name_of_folder>:/app`
4. run `docker-compose up -d`

NB when changes are made locally, don't forget to rerun `rsync` to push the changes to the remote system.

Its not perfect but it works. An issue is ongoing https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/179

Other project that attempt to solve this include [docker-rsync](https://github.com/synack/docker-rsync)

Comment: rsync needs to be installed on remote system it seems
`
sh: rsync: not found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: remote command not found (code 127) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-45/rsync/io.c(453) [sender=2.6.9]
`
How did you get it to work?

Comment: rsync needs to be installed on your local system

Comment: Using these steps completely locks up my digitalocean host.. The files transfer over fine, but when I try to reconnect to the host with docker-machine, I get `exit status 255` and have to completely recreate the machine.

Comment: Created a script for the solution mentioned here. Works on latest `docker 1.10` and `docker-machine 0.6.0` https://gist.github.com/cristobal/fcb0987871d7e1f7449e

Comment: @cristobal it looks like you scripted the mount solution, not the rsync solution?

Comment: Well the reason i created a mount solution, is due to how our stuff is setup internally at work . We have to mount 300GB+ volumes that contain DB files. This is some legacy stuff :/

Comment: It also seems that i posted the solution to the wrong thread here :P

Comment: What's the up-to-date answer here?

Answer (score 14):

At the moment I can't really see any way to mount volumes on machines, so the approach by now would be to somehow copy or sync the files you need into the machine.

There are [conversations](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/179) on how to solve this issue on the docker-machine's github repo. Someone made a [pull request](https://github.com/docker/machine/pull/1140) implementing [scp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) on docker-machine and it's already merged on master, so it's very likely that the next release will include it.

Since it's not yet released, by now I would recommend that if you have your code hosted on github, just clone your repo before you run the app

```
web:
  build: .
  command: git clone https://github.com/my/repo.git; ./repo/run_web.sh
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    - db:db
    - rabbitmq:rabbit
    - redis:redis
```

Update: Looking further I found that the feature is already available in the [latest binaries](https://docker-machine-builds.evanhazlett.com/latest/), when you get them you'll be able to copy your local project running a command like this:

```
docker-machine scp -r . dev:/home/docker/project
```

Being this the general form:

```
docker-machine scp [machine:][path] [machine:][path]
```

So you can copy files from, to and between machines.

Cheers!1

Comment: the documentation for docker-machine scp : https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/scp/

Comment: this method is very slow :(

Answer (score 5):

Since October 2017 there is a new command for docker-machine that does the trick, but make sure there is nothing in the directory before executing it, otherwise it might get lost:

`docker-machine mount <machine-name>:<guest-path> <host-path>`

Check the docs for more information: https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/mount/

PR with the change: https://github.com/docker/machine/pull/4018

Comment: Just unbelievably, from the Docker Machine documentation (that you linked), it is - literally - impossible to know that the order in the command is `...:<guest-path> <host-path>` (rather than the other way around).  Something as simple and critical as that to note in documentation ... just isn't!

Comment: I guess it is not very explicit, you are right. It has to be guessed from the list of commands

Comment: It does the trick, but in other way. It allows to mount docker-machine dir on your local machine.
Unfortunately it doesn't allow other way :(

Answer (score 4):

If you choose the rsync option with docker-machine, you can combine it with the `docker-machine ssh <machinename>` command like this:

`rsync -rvz --rsh='docker-machine ssh <machinename>' --progress <local_directory_to_sync_to> :<host_directory_to_sync_to>`

It uses this command format of rsync, leaving `HOST` blank:

`rsync [OPTION]... SRC [SRC]... [USER@]HOST:DEST`

(http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/rsync1.html)

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured out how to upgrade Windows Docker Toolbox to v1.12.5 and keep my volumes working by adding a shared folder in `Oracle VM VirtualBox` manager and disabling path conversion. If you have Windows 10+ then you're best to use the newer Docker for Windows.

**1st the upgrade Pain:**

1. Uninstall VirtualBox first.

   - Yep that may break stuff in other tools like Android Studio. Thanks Docker :(
2. Install new version of Docker Toolbox.

**Redis Database Example:**

  `redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379"
    volumes:
      - "/var/db/redis:/data:rw"`

In Docker Quickstart Terminal ....

1. run `docker-machine stop default` - Ensure VM is haulted

In Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager ...

2. Added a shared folder in `default` VM via or command line

   - `D:\Projects\MyProject\db` => `/var/db`

In `docker-compose.yml`...

3. Mapped redis volume as: `"/var/db/redis:/data:rw"`

In Docker Quickstart Terminal ....

4. Set `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=0` (for Toolbox version >= 1.9.0)
5. run `docker-machine start default` to restart the VM.
6. `cd D:\Projects\MyProject\`
7. `docker-compose up` should work now.

Now creates redis database in `D:\Projects\MyProject\db\redis\dump.rdb`

**Why avoid relative host paths?**

I *avoided relative host paths* for Windows Toolbox as they may introduce invalid '\' chars. It's not as nice as using paths relative to `docker-compose.yml` but at least my fellow developers can easily do it even if their project folder is elsewhere without having to hack the `docker-compose.yml` file (bad for SCM).

**Original Issue**

FYI ... Here is the original error I got when I used nice clean relative paths that used to work just fine for older versions.  My volume mapping used to be just `"./db/redis:/data:rw"`

`ERROR: for redis  Cannot create container for service redis: Invalid bind mount spec "D:\\Projects\\MyProject\\db\\redis:/data:rw": Invalid volume specification: 'D:\Projects\MyProject\db\redis:/data`

This breaks for two reasons ..

1. It can't access `D:` drive
2. Volume paths can't include `\` characters

   - `docker-compose` adds them and then blames you for it !!
   - Use `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=0` to stop this nonsense.

I recommend documenting your additional VM shared folder mapping in your `docker-compose.yml` file as you may need to uninstall VirtualBox again and reset the shared folder and anyway your fellow devs will love you for it.

Comment: you sir, are a fine person

Answer (score 1):

All other answers were good for the time but now (Docker Toolbox v18.09.3) all works out of the box. You just need to add a shared folder into VirtualBox VM.

Docker Toolbox automatically adds `C:\Users` as shared folder `/c/Users` under virtual linux machine (using Virtual Box shared folders feature), so if your `docker-compose.yml` file is located somewhere under this path and you mount host machine's directories only under this path - all should work out of the box.

For example:

`C:\Users\username\my-project\docker-compose.yml`:

```
...
  volumes:
    - .:/app
...
```

The `.` path will be automatically converted to absolute path `C:\Users\username\my-project` and then to `/c/Users/username/my-project`. And this is exactly how this path is seen from the point of view of linux virtual machine (you can check it: `docker-machine ssh` and then `ls /c/Users/username/my-project`). So, the final mount will be `/c/Users/username/my-project:/app`.

All works transparently for you.

But this doesn't work if your host mount path is not under `C:\Users` path. For example, if you put the same `docker-compose.yml` under `D:\dev\my-project`.

This can be fixed easily though.

1. Stop the virtual machine (`docker-machine stop`).
2. Open Virtual Box GUI, open Settings of Virtual Machine named `default`, open `Shared Folders` section and add the new shared folder:

   - Folder Path: `D:\dev`
   - Folder Name: `d/dev`

   Press `OK` twice and close Virtual Box GUI.
3. Start the virtual machine (`docker-machine start`).

That's all. All paths of host machine under `D:\dev` should work now in `docker-compose.yml` mounts.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done witch combination of three tools:
`docker-machine mount`, `rsync`, `inotifywait`

> **TL;DR**
>
> Script based on all below [is here](https://github.com/raven-wing/syncmachine)

Let's say you have your `docker-compose.yml` and `run_web.sh` in `/home/jdcaballerov/web`

1. Mount directory **on machine** which has **same path** as you have it on your host `docker-machine machine:/home/jdcaballerov/web /tmp/some_random_dir`
2. Synchronize mounted directory with dir on your host `rsync -r /home/jdcaballerov/web /tmp/some_random_dir`
3. Synchronize on every change of files in your directory:

   ```
   inotifywait -r -m -e close_write --format '%w%f' /home/jdcaballerov/web | while read CHANGED_FILE
   do
       rsync /home/jdcaballerov/web /tmp/some_random_dir
   done
   ```

**BE AWARE** - there are two directories which has same path - one is on your local (host) machine, second is on docker machine.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `run_web.sh` file is in the same directory as your `docker-compose.yml` file. Then the command should be `command: /app/run_web.sh`.

Unless the `Dockerfile` (that you are not disclosing) takes care of putting the `run_web.sh` file into the Docker image.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It is on the same directory. However I notice the volume is not being mounted. Files are not available, and thats the question. How to add them. The structure is similar to http://www.syncano.com/configuring-running-django-celery-docker-containers-pt-1/

Comment: Make sure you have the latest versions of both docker and dicker-compose.

Comment: docker: Docker version 1.6.0, build 4749651, docker-machine version 0.2.0 (8b9eaf2), docker-compose 1.2.0

Comment: Have you modified the Dockerfile from http://www.syncano.com/configuring-running-django-celery-docker-containers-pt-1/ in any way?

Comment: Yes, I do add the code, create the directory. The trouble is that when docker-compose executes it overwrites the volume:  volumes:
    - .:/app and leaves an empty directory. I commented volumes in compose and it works.

Answer (score 0):

After summarize posts here, attached updated script,  to create additional host mount point and automount when Virtualbox restart. The working environment brief as below:
 - Windows 7
 - docker-machine.exe version 0.7.0
 - VirtualBox 5.0.22

```
    #!env bash

    : ${NAME:=default}
    : ${SHARE:=c/Proj}
    : ${MOUNT:=/c/Proj}
    : ${VBOXMGR:=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe}
    SCRIPT=/mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh

    ## set -x
    docker-machine stop $NAME
    "$VBOXMGR" sharedfolder add $NAME --name c/Proj --hostpath 'c:\' --automount 2>/dev/null || :
    docker-machine start $NAME
    docker-machine env $NAME

    docker-machine ssh $NAME 'echo "mkdir -p $MOUNT" | sudo tee $SCRIPT'
    docker-machine ssh $NAME 'echo "sudo mount -t vboxsf -o rw,user $SHARE $MOUNT" |  sudo tee -a $SCRIPT'
    docker-machine ssh $NAME 'sudo chmod +x /mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh'
    docker-machine ssh $NAME 'sudo /mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh'
    #docker-machine ssh $NAME 'ls $MOUNT'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using docker-machine 0.12.2 with the virtualbox drive on my local machine. I found that there is a directory `/hosthome/$(user name)` from where you have access to local files.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd mention I've been using 18.03.1-ce-win65 (17513) on Windows 10 and I noticed that if you've previously shared a drive and cached the credentials, once you change your password docker will start having the volumes mounted within containers as blank.

It gives no indication that what is actually happening is that it is now failing to access the shared with the old cached credentials.
The solution in this scenario is to reset the credentials either through the UI (Settings->Shared drives) or to disable then renable drive sharing and enter the new password.

It would be useful if docker-compose gave an error in these situations.