# no django app created when following the docker-compose tutorial

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I'm following the docker-compose tutorial, to try and figure out how to get a django app to deploy: http://docs.docker.com/compose/django/

And everything's going smoothly (the app even works!) but the django project folder `composeexample` isn't created in my local project directory.

I'm left with a working "It Works!" page after running:

`$ docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject composeexample .`

But I can't continue to edit the `composeexample/settings.py`, as the tutorial suggests: The folder doesn't exist on my machine (it does exist in the container, but it's no good to me there!)

**Is the tutorial wrong? Did I not follow it right?**

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Here's the problem, I'm using docker-machine to run this whole process through a remote docker instance. Are the rules about local folder sharing different when using a remote docker machine?

Comment: I guess you want to use `volumes` using `docker-compose` + `docker-machine` Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040708/how-to-mount-local-volumens-in-docker-machine#answer-30512262) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up a dockerfile so that when you do a docker build, it copies your local code onto the container. To get started, you will need to copy the files from container to local. Look here for that. Or just overwrite the directory with your own django app

[Copying files from host to Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907231/copying-files-from-host-to-docker-container)

example:

```
FROM python:2.7
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code/
```

Comment: ie, the tutorial doesn't mention copying the generated code from container to local directory. Shouldn't changes be synced back to the local directory automatically?

Comment: @Oatman don't forget the "." period when running `$ docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject composeexample`

Comment: Thank you, I've double-checked, and that was a typo in my question, rather than a command I ran badly :-P If I run it again, it says `/code/manage.py already exists`

Comment: I just ran through the tutorial quickly, it does work and adds composeexample folder to your local system. Just make the 3 files first, then run `docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject composeexample . ` from that directory.

Comment: Oh dear, I'll tear everything down and start from scratch, give me a moment!

Comment: Oh! I see what I'm doing! I am using docker-machine to do this all remotely. Would that change things?

Comment: I'm not familiar with docker-machine

Comment: No problem, I've updated the Q with the problem. On a different note, you should try it, it's amazingly simple cloud orchestration for docker. https://www.docker.com/docker-machine

Comment: I don't think I'm using docker-machine and I'm also having this issue - how did you ultimate solve it?

Answer (score 0):

ADD . /code/  in docker file will be actually mount your local working directory  inside the docker image.
So you can make changes to code inside your working directory and same will be updated inside the  docker container as  working directory is mounted inside the same.

Use dockerfile as shown in tutorial to generate the image and use the same image for creating container.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and that is because I changed the folder name "/code" in Dockerfile, but forget to change folder name in docker-compose.yum file.
So be sure the folder name in the 2 files are the same.

And actually the container(and all the files) is already created in /var/lib/docker/overlay2/.../diff/code/, that is why the log mentioned about "Successfully built ...", but not copied back to the folder where you trigger the cmd.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue on docker with WSL and tracked it down - it was an issue with volume mounting. Basically to solve this you need to create your project directory in WSL on the mounted c volume on not in a "native" WSL directory. In my case this meant creating my project directory here: /c/Users/seth/proj_dir

You can read more about mounting issues in this excellent WSL/Docker tutorial (search for "Create and modify the new WSL configuration file" and then search again for "docker-compose up": https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly