# DjangoProject doesn't appear in my Docker-Image (Docker toolbox for windows home)

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, docker-toolbox

I'm trying to build a django project using docker-compose, such as it is in the [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) *(i use Docker toolbox for Windows 10 Home)*.

But when i execute the command:

> sudo docker-compose run web django-admin startproject composeexample .

I get an *bash: sudo: command not found*

[image]

---

Then if i execute the same command without "sudo":

> docker-compose run web django-admin startproject composeexample .

**The image is created but the django project folder is not displayed:**

[image: ls command doesn´t show the django project]

Finally, when i run the command again i get:

[image: The project already exists]

Indicating that the project was created in the previous step.

---

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

and the requirements.txt:

```
Django>=2.0,<3.0
psycopg2>=2.7,<3.0
```

Comment: Same issue, did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Figured this out and answered it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64396873/292633

Comment: Does this answer your question? [no django app created when following the docker-compose tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565640/no-django-app-created-when-following-the-docker-compose-tutorial)