# How to get contents generated by a docker container on the local fileystem

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

### **EDIT**: I'm not longer using docker so I'll not be able to test answers to this question

thanks to all for the suggestions!

---

> TL;DR: can you point me to a simple example of an image that writes
> changes to a volume shared between the container and the host
> filesystem?

Hi,

I have some trouble understanding how volumes work.

I've read the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) and also [understanding volumes](http://container-solutions.com/understanding-volumes-docker/)

## What I'm trying to do

- I have an image that makes a composer installation of wordpress on RUN to /var/tmp/html
- then ONBUILD I use some information from docker-compose.yml ENVIRONMENT variables to make some more operations to /var/tmp/html
- As the last step I want everything to be copied to /var/www/html and have it acessessible from the composer (be able to run apache pointing to those files) and from the local filesystem (I will code things to this html directory)

## What I have right now

### Test 1

[Dockerfile](https://github.com/MiquelAdell/composed_wordpress/blob/53240e67e9c4ba67ab68fc5d68b196d556d12c8e/Dockerfile)

[docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/MiquelAdell/miquelladell_v2/blob/e509d52130e63654bdb2e1de4344d765e957b868/docker-compose.yml)

*The link above is a link to the specific version on github of those files*

*This test is just everything to install wordpress without any volume information*

*Result*

Bashing into the image and listing /var/www/html

I get:

```
root@4484ccdb63ca:/var/www/html# ls -al
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 6 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 21 11:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root     root     4096 Jan 21 11:45 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   10 Jan 21 10:47 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  138 Jan 21 10:47 composer.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 3718 Jan 21 10:47 composer.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  428 Jan 21 10:47 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 6 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 21 11:45 vendor
drwxr-xr-x 8 www-data www-data 4096 Jan 21 11:45 wordpress
```

wich is **ok**

and listing ./html on the local filesystem I get

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 miqueladell  staff  102 Jan 21 10:33 .
drwxr-xr-x  11 miqueladell  staff  374 Jan 21 13:04 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 miqueladell  staff    0 Jan 21 10:33 foo
```

which is **wrong** but totally expected. The files are ok on the container but have nothing to do outside the container because I did not provide any volume information.

### Test 2

[Dockerfile](https://github.com/MiquelAdell/composed_wordpress/blob/53240e67e9c4ba67ab68fc5d68b196d556d12c8e/Dockerfile)

[docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/MiquelAdell/miquelladell_v2/blob/e509d52130e63654bdb2e1de4344d765e957b868/docker-compose.yml)

*The link above is a link to the specific version on github of those files*

*adds VOLUME on Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml*

this is a paste of the diff

**Dockerfile**

```
- # VOLUME /var/www/html/
+ VOLUME /var/www/html/
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
-  # volumes:
-  #    - .html:/var/www/html/
+  volumes:
+     - ./html:/var/www/html/
```

The result of building the image and running the cointainer is both empty an empty html directory on the container and no change to the local filesystem

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I've created a minimal failing version of this question: [How to get contents generated by a docker container on the local fileystem (minimal failing example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34926906/how-to-get-contents-generated-by-a-docker-container-on-the-local-fileystem-mini)

Comment: Does [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040708/how-to-mount-local-volumes-in-docker-machine?rq=1) helps ?

Comment: I think it doesn't. It does offer a solution to "getting the files there" but I'm building a base for web development so I really need to have the files shared between local and container filesystem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a small misunderstanding of what `VOLUME` in your `Dockerfile` does and what `-v` does when you run a docker container.

The fundamental difference between `VOLUME` and -v is this: -v will mount existing files from your operating system inside your docker container and `VOLUME` will create a new, empty volume on your host (stored in /var/lib/docker/xxxxx) and mount it inside your container.

Example:

We have a file test-file in /home/test/

```
cmckinnel at arch in /home/test
$ ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 cmckinnel adm  4096 Jan 21 14:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root      root 4096 Jan 21 14:40 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 cmckinnel adm     0 Jan 21 14:40 test-file
```

We want to mount this directory inside our docker container so when we change a file on our host, it changes inside the container.

This is what you're currently doing (creating an empty `VOLUME` inside your container at `/home/test`):

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

VOLUME /home/test
```

Build this image and run a container from it:

```
$ docker build -t test-creating-volume .
$ docker run -ti test-creating-volume bash
$ cd /home/test
$ ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 21 14:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 21 14:41 ../
```

What you actually want to do instead is use `-v` when you `docker run`:

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
```

Build this image and run a container from it:

```
$ docker build -t test-mounting-volume .
$ docker run -ti -v /home/test:/home/test test-mounting-volume bash
$ cd /home/test
$ ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 1000 adm  4096 Jan 21 14:40 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 21 14:51 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 adm     0 Jan 21 14:40 test-file
```

**Edit**

Oops, I think your actual problem above is you don't have the full path in your `volume:` declaration in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

Example:

docker-compose.yml (note `.home` doesn't exist)

```
test-mounting-volume:
    image: test-mounting-volume:
    volumes:
        - .home:/home/test
```

Then:

```
$ docker-compose run test-mounting-volume
$ cd /home/test
$ ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 21 15:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 21 15:01 ../
```

But if you put the full path:

docker-compose.yml:

```
test-mounting-volume:
    image: test-mounting-volume:
    volumes:
        - /home/test:/home/test
```

Then:

```
$ docker-compose run test-mounting-volume
$ cd /home/test
$ ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jan 21 15:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 21 15:01 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 adm     0 Jan 21 14:40 test-file
```

Comment: Yes, you were right about my misunderstanding. Isn't there a way to get the -v functionality in a docker-compose declaration? I'm trying to build a self building environment on tutum and it relies on them. Thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: Sorry just been fact checking myself - I think your problem is you don't have the full path in your `docker-compose.yml` file on both sides of the `:`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Volumes function like mountpoints so when a volume is mounted the contents of the mount point are the ones that get to the container.

As answered in [this (simplified) question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34932934/704097) the solution is to do the operations on an entrypoint that will get executed after the volume is mounted.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over version 2 of your Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file I suggest the following edits:

**Dockerfile**

Around Line 70: change from

```
WORKDIR /tmp/html

ONBUILD RUN rsync --ignore-existing -a /tmp/html/ .
```

to

```
WORKDIR /var/www/html

ONBUILD RUN rsync --ignore-existing -a /tmp/html/ .
```

`WORKDIR` sets the default path for scripts being run (and when you log into the container).

In your first example you are effectively copying the contents of `/tmp/html` to itself with rsync, and then later you bin that directory. Plus this directory isn't exposed outside the container.

With the above change, you will copy the contents of `/tmp/html` to the `/var/www/html`, which is then exposed outside the container, and later mapped to your local machine using the docker-compose file.

**Docker-compose.yml**

Try the following file:

```
wordpress:
image: miqueladell/composed_wordpress_test
links:
    - wordpress_db:mysql
environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=miqueladell.dev
    - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
   - ./html:/var/www/html

wordpress_db:
  image: miqueladell/mariadb-utf8mb4
  environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```